# Mule dynamic conditions

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I defined an external xml which contains few expressions.

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring-security="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
      xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
          http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.1/mule-spring-security.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="conditions" class="java.util.ArrayList" name="conditions">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>#[flowVars.price == '1000']</beans:value>
                <beans:value>...</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

</mule>
```

In the main flow i would like to evaluate this experssions, but the result is always true. Here is what i've done so far.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:my-conf-dir/expressions.xml"/>
</spring:beans>

<flow name="mainFlow" doc:name="mainFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <expression-filter expression="#[payload != '/favicon.ico']" doc:name="Expression"/>

    <set-variable variableName="price" value="1001" doc:name="Set Price" />

    <foreach collection="#[app.registry.get('conditions')]" doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="Condition: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <choice>
            <when expression="#[payload]">
                <logger message="OK" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="KO" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Is there any way to evaluate a list of expressions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could evaluate the expressions using a java component and accessing the `eventContext.getMuleContext().getExpressionLanguage().evaluate` method.

HTH, Marcos

Comment: Great! Yes some expression shortcuts could not be available using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there what you are trying to do can not be done, at least not in the current way.

When you send a value to MEL like you're trying to do it evaluate it as a literal.
So the true is not a true is just the literal:

## [flowVars.price == '1000']

What you could do is get #[flowVars['price'].equals(payload)] where payload is the value of the list.
Please notice I used equals as you're comparing strings.

May be if you provide some more context we can get a better idea on how to achieve what you want